# How to click a button on Facebook using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I wanted to click a "see more" button on a Facebook page, but nothing seems to work.
The code is something like this:

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
 browser.get(url)
 browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
 browser.find_element_by_id("reaction_profile_pager1").click()
 print("Click Successfull")
 time.sleep(2)
```

I have tried literally every way one can find the thing to click in selenium (id, class, link name, name, etc.) and there is always a different error. However, I may have messed up with Xpath.

This is how the page code looks like:
[image: Code]

[Here is the link to that](https://www.facebook.com/ufi/reaction/profile/browser/?ft_ent_identifier=ZmVlZGJhY2s6OTA5OTI5MjQ2MDk0OTY3&av=100004942573538)

The only thing that I want to do is press all "see more" buttons until no more is left.
I hope that someone knows what to do. Thank you for replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class=\"clearfix mtm uiMorePager stat_elem _52jv\"]").click()
```

Comment: Well, buttons are not the only ones, which have rel='async', which is fine as long as it works, but, unfortunately, it doesn't(
Here's the error: https://pastebin.com/fN5m1q9Q

Comment: Edited, would you try again

Comment: No, that didn't work either. I think that error is the same, but here it is: https://pastebin.com/fNFTc9gK
Also, I had to shield quotes with a backslash, because otherwise, the syntax is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That didn't work either for me, but I ended up doing this: ```            browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class=\"clearfix mtm uiMorePager stat_elem _52jv\"]").click()
```. You helped a lot though. You may edit your answer and i'll verify it.